# Keep the same number of images inside a dynamic flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

you have to help me. I have a deadline in hours, I haven't slept in ages and I'm ripping my hair out here.

Look, here's my [current project](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/48/)

css:

```
    .container {overflow: hidden; width: 100%}
    .flexslider {max-width: 800px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto}
    .content {background: #f2f2f2; max-width: 800px; display: block; margin: 0 auto}
    .flex-viewport {overflow: hidden !important}
```

script:

```
        // flexslider
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({   
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: true,
            itemWidth: 410,
            itemMargin: 5,
            minItems: 1,
            maxItems: 1
        });
```

Basically,  on the mobile viewport I want 1 item centered and visible, but on higher viewports I would like 3. I can tweak the parameters above with code when the window changes size. That's not the issue.

The issue is how flexslider falls to pieces when you resize the browser (despite its name). The **one** hero image I want on display might appear half on half off with another image or not at all. Infuriating, inconsitent results.

Please help, I want one image dead center on lower viewports, and three images dead center on higher viewports.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
itemWidth: 410,
itemMargin: 5,
```

from your script and try it.

Comment: That definitely fixed it solidly for the one image, so thanks for that, but what about when I want to move through the three images?

Comment: provide jsfiddle for that too, lets see if I can help you with that too.

Comment: I believe [this is the documentation for dynamic flex sliders](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html), and should be used when creating a responsive website. However, even in their example the images don't add up at times! [this template](http://ddthemesdemo.com/biosphere/) manages to get their sliders to line up really well, though, and I'm wondering how they do it! (Here's a js fiddle, demonstrating their example)[http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/52/]. The slides line up terribly in this compared to the template though... thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using more than one item:

```
itemWidth: $('.flexslider').width()/4
```

Here I am dividing total width of FlexSlider with item count. http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/53/

This may not be best solution, but I believe it will work for you.